# How to setup MongoDB with Django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-nonrel, django-mongodb-engine

I've followed numerous tutorials on how to setup a Django project with MongoDB but still get the same errors when running the command for testing:

```
python manage.py runsever
```

Here is the link I've been following:

http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/blog/django/2010/05/MongoDB-backend-for-Django-nonrel-released

Here are the errors I get from the above command:

```
Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x10d266210>>
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 91, in inner_run
self.validate(display_num_errors=True)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 23, in get_validation_errors
from django.db import models, connection

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 92, in __getitem__
backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])

 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 24, in load_backend
return import_module('.base', backend_name)

 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
__import__(name)

File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/django_mongodb_engine/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

I have no idea why this isn't working and ideally I just want a database setup to use specifically for storing JSON documents. Is there an easier alternative to connecting Django with another database that is ideal for storing JSON information?

Comment: Are you using MongoDB 2.4? Because I had a project in django-nonrel and mongo that worked fine until I upgraded to 2.4, now they seem to not work together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clarification:

INSTALLED_APPS should be tuple.

He gets `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'insert'` because mongodb does not handle tuple INSTALLED_APPS correctly. The default in mongodb is insert list. This is already fix before but now it's gone.

There suggestion are:

- changing your settings.INSTALLED_APPS to a list instead of a tuple. (which is bad for me)
- correct their code by adding the patch

Comment: @lciamp mongoDB is inserted by list that's why he gets that error. Because his installed app is tuple which conflict to mongoDB insert list, understand? To fix his problem he can use insert or add the patch to run it correctly

Answer (score 0):

There is a new package called djongo for fully nosql support with mongoDB:
 - https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/

you cann install ist in your venv:

```
pip install djongo
```